# How to detect the changed poco entities in an ObservableCollection over wcf in N-Tier architecture?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I have following layers in my applicaiton
Date Layer (reference to Model)
Business Layer(reference to Model ,Data)
Model
Service(WCF)-(reference to Model,Business Layer)
UI (WPF/Silver Light) - Connected via WCF service

How do i detect the changed poco entities in an ObservableCollection in UI layer?
for sending it back to server from client side for saving ? instead of sending all data back to sever side(via WCF)?

or

how to perform add/delete/update operation on entities in the collection in UI layer?

I am using 
VS2010/2012
C#
EF 5
ADO.NET POCOEntityGenerator With WCF Support(for generating .tt templates from Model.edmx)
SQL Server 2012

Even though searched a lot of places I didn't find a proper solution..
please help if any ideas...

Thanks...

The method i followed to create My application is given below link

http://www.toplinestrategies.com/dotneters/net/wcf-entity-framework-and-n-tier-solutions-part-2/?lang=en/comment-page-1/#comment-1954

Answer (score 0):

Only proper solution is to do the change tracking manually. Each POCO object will have `IsDirty` property and each property of this object will have `IsDirty = true` in it's setter.

One way to make it less manual would be to create a framework, that will create wrapper classes, that will do this for you, but this requires large dose of reflection and code-generation. Also, it will still require all properties to be defined as virtual.

But generally, you want to refrain from making UI that would require this kind of tracking. When you want to change an entity, load only that entity in Edit window.

Comment: please give a small piece of codes for showing the save() function in UI layer for changed values..

Comment: @Sadique Thats not where the problem is, is there? The save will just pick ones that have IsDirty set to true and send them to WCF for saving. The problem is to make sure changing any data in POCO object sets the IsDirty.

Comment: The problem is to make sure changing any data in POCO object sets the IsDirty!!... Yes you are correct..!! but i dont know how to use IsDirty with POCO object sets.. If you provide any sample app it will be a great help...

Answer (score 0):

POCOs are well-suited for transmitting data between client and server. However, if you’re looking for objects to actually work with on client and/or server side you may want to consider using self-tracking entities (STE) as these entities contain logic to track their actual changes and status.

Yet a better solution is to use the N-Tier Entity Framework which provides functionality to work with EF in n-tier applications. See http://ntieref.codeplex.com/ for more details.

Comment: I already visited the link that you provided... But i am getting a lot of errors and not working properly while using N-Tier Entity Framework template. And no more details are available about it other than a document attached in the link.

Comment: @Sadique: Please feel free to post issues or questions on n-tier entity framework here at stackoverflow to get support. In addition to the user guide there are also sample applications for download at codeplex.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using EF, then your entities have a 'HasChanges' flag you can test against before submitting changes to your context.
e.g.

```
if (this.CurrentEntity.HasChanges || CurrentEntity.EntityState == EntityState.New)
{
this.SubjectContext.SubmitChanges(Submit_Completed, saveDetails);
}
```

Comment: MyServiceClient service = new MyServiceClient();ObservableCollection<TypeOfMyClass> clMyCollection=new ObservableCollection<TypeOfMyClass>(); clMyCollection=service.GetMyMethod("Parameter"); I used to bind this colletion to a devexpress gridcontrol like (grdcntrl.ItemSource=clMyCollection). so if i change any cell or add a new row or delete a row i need that specific row to be send back to the server via wcf service how to do?

Comment: DataContext wont be available in UI layer since it is communicated over WCF.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you were trying to manage your entities in a UI layer. Question arises of why? Separating UI from code is surely a good thing. Good luck finding the answer.

Comment: I need my app. in WPF & Silver light as well as in SQL & Oracle so that i did it in this way, And Mr.Euphoric said about IsDirty property but i am looking for how to implement it... if you could please help... Thanks..

Comment: He basically said you'd have to manage the change tracking yourself (manually). But also it would be easier if you didn't make UI that had to keep track of the entity states!
I use Silverlight too, but use MVVM. In this way I would set my ItemSource through binding to a view model collection of entities. Those entities could then be within a context and changes tracked automatically.